# Calender control to display a date event

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net

I have a DB table (SQL Server) that contains two fields: `EmployeeNumber` and `HiringDate`.

I want a calender control in ASP.NET which will display the events for all the `HiringDate's` , and the `EmployeeNumber` for each employee hired on that date.

Does anyone know of a control which provides this functionality?

Comment: Why don't you display it in a gridview control?

Comment: cause I want a display like a calender.
for example:
http://jebarson.info/wp-content/uploads/2011/2/Outlook%20Calendar.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the calendar control just fine; you just have to tap into the dayrender event, and then manually write HTML for every event you want to display in that time slot.  There's nothing out of the box that supports data binding, that I know of, that isn't a third party control costing money.

Another great client-side plugin that may be of use is [JQuery fullcalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/), which takes JSON to bind to.